# differentiate $g(f(x),x)$ with respect to $f(x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $g(y,x)$ which is differentiable with respect to both arguments. I know that $y=f(x)$ is bijective, and thus the inverse function exists $x = f^{-1}(y)$. My question is when I calculate 
$$\frac{d g(y,x)}{d y}$$
should I care about $x$ as well because $x$ implicitly changes when $y$ changes?

I know that when I calculate 
$$\frac{d g(y,x)}{d x} $$
I have to take into account the fact that $y=f(x)$ also changes in $x$

Comment: In "$\dfrac{\partial g(y,x)}{\partial y}$", $g(y,x)$ means a function with two independent arguments, so there's no need to care about $x$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I am not sure about what you mean by "independent arguments". Also when I take a derivative with respect to $x$, then I have to care about $y$ as well right?

Comment: Plz see the [wiki page for "function argument"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function).  What type of derivative are you refering to? Partial or total?  The question context shows the former.

Comment: I refer to total differentiation

Comment: So that's $d$ instead of $\partial$.

Comment: Yes, I changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $$\frac{\frac{\text dg}{\text dx}}{\frac{\text dg}{\text dy}} = \frac{\text dy}{\text dx} = f'(x) \Rightarrow \frac{\text dg}{\text dy} = \frac{1}{f'(x)} \frac{\text dg}{\text dx}$$

So, if you calculate $\frac{\text dg}{\text dx}$ by taking $f(x)$ into account, you can easily calculate $\frac{\text dg}{\text dy}$ with this relationship.